# How to call directive from template html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ProfileTemplateHTML" >
    <div class="container profilepopup-cont" align="center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 zero-margin-padding" align="center">
                <img id="DisplayImage" ng-src={{model.picLarge}} class="img-circle">
            </div>
...
</script>
```

In this html template file i have to call a directive.My directive name is 'help'.But if i add  to call the directive it is not working.
how to call a directive inside html template in angularjs?

Comment: IF i use <help></help> to call the directive inside html its not working

Comment: After compilation of your template directive inside your template will work. you can use $compile service to compile it manually

Comment: @murli2308 Can you tell me how to compile it manually?

Comment: your question isn't really clear.  What does "not working" mean?  There is no reason that you can't use a directive inside a template;  In order to understand what your issue is, we would need to know how you are invoking this template.

Comment: Provide the directive JS code as well. What's the name of the directive? The correct name (defined in the JS file) should be `profilepopupCont` (not `profilepopup-cont`). What is the directive `restrict` attribute? It should include 'A'.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the directive in these ways

1. As an attribute

```html
<div help>
 ...
  
 </div>
```

2. As a separate tag

```html
<page>
  
  //your code
  
</page>
```

Comment: You can do it with a class `<span class="help"></span>` and comment `<!-- help -->` also.

Comment: Her question is not about how to define directive in html, her question is why is it not working inside ng-template.

Comment: I have tried keeping it in div,page,span.Its not working!

Comment: directive can be also applied by setting class of an arbitrary tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i fully understand the question. 
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/aifarfa/u16we3k8/) is a jsfiddle to demonstrate how to use custom directive inside ng-template.

or try this..

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .directive('help', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div>Help! {{info}}</div>',
      scope: {
        info: '@info'
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$log',
    function($log) {
      this.hello = 'This is MainCtrl';
      this.template = 'profile-template.html';

      //construct
      $log.debug('DemoCtrl has been loaded');
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demo">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="profile-template.html">
    <div>this is profile-template.html</div>
    <div help info="this is directive info."></div>
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <h2>just a demo</h2>
    <div>{{main.hello}}, include template from {{main.template}}</div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-include src="main.template"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```