# How to call an angular directive within an a tag whilst passing a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, pug, angular-directive

I would like to do something like this:

```
<a <myDir myVar="someInput"></myDir>>Call myDir</A>
```

However I'm realising you can't nest a directive within an a tag and set parameters this way.

I'm actually using jade though. I call the directive fine with.

```
a(myDir) Call myDir
```

but am unsure how to pass the variable to the directive. I've tried the equivalent jade to the above html, which is this:

```
a(myDir(myVar="someInput")) Call myDir
```

As its an optional parameter I use the '=?' syntax in the directive.

However the issue is definitely the syntax for calling the function in jade.

Answer (score 0):

So after much failure this is how you do it.

// In the HTML/Jade

```
a(myDir info="someInput")
```

// In the Directive

```
scope: {
    info: '@?info'
}
```

Check out this question and @aifarfa's answer for an example. Though the question is different it's a perfect example of what I wanted to do.

[How to call directive from template html in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264442/how-to-call-directive-from-template-html-in-angularjs)